# Create an array with values for each loop through

Tags: php

I'm within a foreach loop and I'd like to add multiple values to an array

```
$allcustomers = array();
foreach ($customers as $entry) {
  $allcustomers['User Email'] = $user_meta['0']['user_email'];
  $allcustomers['Customer ID'] = $customer_id;
}
```

This is what it's outputting:

```
Array
(
    [User Email] => email@gmail.com
    [Customer ID] => 18060
)
```

So it's just overwriting the one array constantly. I want it to output the same but for every customer.

How do I create an array for each loop?

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User Email] => email@domain.com
            [Customer ID] => 184
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User Email] => email@domain.com
            [Customer ID] => 185
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [User Email] => email@domain.com
            [Customer ID] => 183
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$allcustomers = array();
foreach ($customers as $entry) {
    $allcustomers[] = [
        'User Email' => $user_meta['0']['user_email'],
        'Customer ID' => $customer_id,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Nope. What's the problem with subarrays?

Comment: But your initial code creates array with data sitting on top level, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. If you want different array of  **User Email** and **Customer ID**

```
$allcustomers = array();
    foreach ($customers as $entry) {
      $allcustomers['User Email'][] = $user_meta['0']['user_email'];
      $allcustomers['Customer ID'][] = $customer_id;
    }
```

Or you want in same array then.

```
$allcustomers = array();
foreach ($customers as $entry) {
    $allcustomers[] = [
        'User Email' => $user_meta['0']['user_email'],
        'Customer ID' => $customer_id,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($customers as $user_meta){
allValues[] = [
    'User Email' => $user_meta['0']['user_email'],
    'Customer ID' => $customer_id
];}
```

Where did you set customer_id? I think you need to get it from the user meta too.

Best regards